# How to insert data in db with the methode afterJob

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch

In my application I have to insert somme data in db, this data contian the ExitStatut of the Job,
my code is

```
 @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecutionContext.get(ConstantesApps.TRACE) != null) {
            Trace trace = (Trace)jobExecutionContext.get(ConstantesApps.TRACE);
            trace.setHeureFinTraitement(jobExecution.getEndTime());
            trace.setCodeRetour(getCodeRetour(jobExecution));
            traceRepository.update(trace);
        }

    }
```

i have this exception :

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:993) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342) ~[spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.flush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

well the below piece of code which I wrote , worked for me --

In you Main class - load your application context in a static variable - APP_CONTEXT

If you are not using XML based approach - then get the dataSource by auto-wiring it and then you can use below code -

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt= null;

    try {


    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) Main.APP_CONTEXT
            .getBean("dataSource");

     conn = dataSource.getConnection();
     pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(" your SQL query to insert ");
 pstmtMstr.executeQuery();




    } catch (Exception e) {

    }finally{

        if(pstmt!=null){
            pstmt.close();
        }if(conn!=null){
            conn.close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was fighting in order to make an update at the end of a job, and it worked this way. A very simple solution since I don't know much about spring-batch.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is very clear - you are invoking this code outside of transaction boundaries. You had committed or rolled back your transaction before this code executed or `afterJob` is executed in a separate thread.

In both cases you need to define transactional context in which `afterJob` is executed.

Comment: Dragan, where i can define this context,

Comment: That highly depends on your environment and use cases. Since you use Spring, you'll need to know how [Spring transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) works.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly calling `traceRepository.update(trace);` which could be a Spring `@Repository` bean but not annotated with `@Transactional`.

Instead you can call some Service method that is annotated with `@Transactional`. From that Service method you can invoke `traceRepository.update(trace);` which will run in transactional context.

Comment: my Repository is annotated with @transactional annotation, and i  insert the data in the method write this problem persist just in after Job method

Comment: Is your Job is plain Quartz bean or registered using Spring's QuartzJobBean?

Comment: Then how are you obtaining the reference to traceRepository in you Quartz Job?